# generate Grid from template

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Howdy, 
I've got another question regarding phone 7... I want to generate a couple of Grids in a stackpanel - since they all have the same layout I thought it would be a great idea to use DataTemplates ...

But then I found that the GRID Object has no "DataTemplate" Property and now I'm kinda stuck ... the template which I use is the following:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Speise">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Height="36" Margin="8,43,104,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" Margin="0,44,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The way I now thought of creating my objects is:

Grid blubber = (Grid)this.Resources["Speise"];

But that is not working ... I think it's again a really short thing, but I have no clue of how to google for it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the phone the Grid does not support data templating as it's purely intented as a container for layout.

Outside of the phone, Silverlight has a DataGrid class which you could use this way but it's not available on WP7.

If you want a simple way of generating a large grid you could look at generating something in code using nested loops to create the rows and columns. Without knowing precisely what you're trying to achieve it's hard to advise further.

Also, in your sample DataTemplate you are using a grid just to hold 2 TextBlocks. This seems overly complex. Would a StackPanel (or something else) not be more appropriate?

Comment: I would like to have the 2 Textblocks next to each other and thought that a grid would be the fastest way to achieve that goal.

Comment: @theXs how do the 2 TextBlocks relate to the other items in the grid

Comment: What do you mean? The grid basically contains just the 2 Textblocks ( one left, one right ). In the final implementation I would like to have those Textblocks clickable :).

Comment: @theXs your original question talks about having the grid with 2 textblocks inside another grid. It was the outer grid to which I was refering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListBox as your container rather than StackPanel. It supports a DataTemplate as you can see here.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)